# Divider Disappears When Adding Floated Tag on Vertical Menu Semantic UI React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm really confused with an issue I can't wrap my head around. For demonstration purposes, I included a vertical Menu component from Semantic UI. As you can see in the first picture, everything is normal and how I want it, but when I add a `floated='right'` tag to `<Menu />`, the bottom dividers disappear.

This is the way it's supposed to be:

[image: This is the way it's supposed to be]

This is what happens when the 'floated' tag is added:

[image: This is what happens when the 'floated' tag is added]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Header, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class MenuExampleText extends Component {
   state = {}

   handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

   render() {
      const { activeItem } = this.state

      return (
         <Menu vertical> // <Menu vertical floated='right'> removes the divider
            <Menu.Item
               name='promotions'
               active={activeItem === 'promotions'}
               onClick={this.handleItemClick}
            >
               <Header as='h4'>Promotions</Header>
               <p>Check out our new promotions</p>
            </Menu.Item>

            <Menu.Item
               name='coupons'
               active={activeItem === 'coupons'}
               onClick={this.handleItemClick}
            >
               <Header as='h4'>Coupons</Header>
               <p>Check out our collection of coupons</p>
            </Menu.Item>

            <Menu.Item
               name='rebates'
               active={activeItem === 'rebates'}
               onClick={this.handleItemClick}
            >
               <Header as='h4'>Rebates</Header>
               <p>Visit our rebate forum for information on claiming rebates</p>
            </Menu.Item>
         </Menu>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: When fiddling with css its helpful to have a live example (to use a browsers debugger to edit the css while the page is rendered). Could you possibly create a minimal HTML/CSS recreation outside of react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can reproduce the issue for us or someone has experienced this issue before I'm not sure if anyone will be able to help you. Reproducing your menu in HTML and using `float:right;` does not appear to have the same issue.

Edit: Updated snippet to more closely follow your codepen and included css fix for `display: none` that was your accepted answer.

```js
const {
  Menu,
  Header
} = semanticUIReact

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state

    return (
      <Menu vertical style={styles.sidebarMenu} floated='right'>
        <Menu.Item
          name='promotions'
          active={activeItem === 'promotions'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        >
          <Header as='h4'>Promotions</Header>
          <p>Check out our new promotions</p>
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item
          name='coupons'
          active={activeItem === 'coupons'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        >
          <Header as='h4'>Coupons</Header>
          <p>Check out our collection of coupons</p>
        </Menu.Item>
        
        <Menu.Item
          name='deals'
          active={activeItem === 'deals'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        >
          <Header as='h4'>Deals</Header>
          <p>Check out our collection of deals</p>
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item
          name='rebates'
          active={activeItem === 'rebates'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        >
          <Header as='h4'>Rebates</Header>
          <p>Visit our rebate forum for information on claiming rebates</p>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
  sidebarMenu: {
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginRight: 0,
        height: '100vh'
    },
}

// ----------------------------------------
// Render
// ----------------------------------------
const mountNode = document.getElementById('react-app-mount')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode)
```

```css
.ui.floated.menu .item:last-child:before { 
  display: block !important;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/semantic-ui-react/dist/umd/semantic-ui-react.min.js"></script>

<div id="react-app-mount"></div>
```

Comment: Indeed it doesn't have the issue in HTML. There must be a bug in Semantic UI React because it turns out the same no matter what I try..

Comment: If you host a page somewhere publicly accessible that has the issue I or someone might be able to debug it that way?

Comment: Yes I've recreated the issue on CodePen. You can access it at this link: https://codepen.io/merrilj/pen/XVKEgW. If you remove floated='right' from <Menu /> the dividers reappear..

Comment: Well I found the offending CSS in semantic.min.css there exists `.ui.floated.menu .item:last-child:before { display: none; }` which removes the divider from the last element. That's what you'll want to correct.

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to fix this in react, but I might suggest attaching a style sheet with something like `.ui.floated.menu .item:last-child:before { display: block !important; }`. Or add that to your own style sheet if your already attaching one.
The only other option would be to add your own div in between the last two elements (or in the last element) and manually style it like the current separator.

Comment: I have an existing stylesheet attached. That seemed to fix the issue, thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers, the best solution I was able to come up with was creating a second menu within the menu item you are floating to the right. This should make it appear normal